# How to get the absolute position in Framework?

Tags: android, layout, position, absolute

I want to get the absolute position of the view in FrameLayout.

I did [getLocationOnScreen()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLocationOnScreen(int[])), but it returned minus values.

(and also did [getLocationInWindow()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLocationInWindow(int[])))

How could I get position?

Comment: I think you can get negative values when one ancestor of your frameLayout is a scrollView

Comment: so How could I solve? is there any way to get actual screen position? Not related to scrollView

Comment: You didn't post your layout, so it's impossible to say. Try to add the current scroll x and scroll y of the ancestor scroll view to the coordonates you get from getLocationXYZ